# how to set the environment variable BRIEFCASE_HOME in BeeWare python

Tags: python-3.x, beeware

I'm going to create a simple android apk file using python and BeeWare
I installed BeeWare and togo in a virtual env
when I write `briefcase new` or `briefcase create` and press Enter, I got this error:

```
The location Briefcase will use to store tools and support files:

    C:\Users\SIR ...\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache

contains spaces. This will cause problems with some tools, preventing
you from building and packaging applications.

You can set the environment variable BRIEFCASE_HOME to specify
a custom location for Briefcase's tools.
```

how can I set a BRIEFCASE_HOME ??
and which code I should use? `briefcase new` or `briefcase create`

thanks in advance for your help.

I used both `briefcase new`  and `briefcase create` but they have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable in Windows using `set`, which takes effect only on the current command prompt window:

```
set BRIEFCASE_HOME=C:\BriefcaseHome
```

Or `setx`, which takes effect on all future command prompt windows, but not the current one. Note there is no equals sign:

```
setx BRIEFCASE_HOME C:\BriefcaseHome
```

Then continue following the tutorial starting with `briefcase new`.